# if request.user_agent().is_mobile: response.view.replace('.html','.mobile.html') doesn't seem to be having any affect

Tags: mobile, web, web2py

Working in web2py, attempting to redesign my website to be more mobile friendly.  Using a user agent switcher in Chrome (verified working with several other web pages that return different formats when coming from a mobile device) but on my site during testing, the darned thing that was recommended by web2py's book to make this doable doesn't want to work.

The below is in default.py for each function being called (index, about, contact, etc.)

```
if request.user_agent().is_mobile:
    response.view.replace('.html','.mobile.html')
```

Additionally, I have index.mobile.html, about.mobile.html and other similarly named views ready to roll.  They are all extending layout.mobile.html, which was modified to use a different css file than layout.html (for non-mobile webbrowsers).

Perhaps I made this more complicated than it needs to be, but I'm rather new to web2py, and web development in general, and am trying to piece together what needs to happen to make my darned website be mobile friendly in the eye's of Google (even though my site looks just fine on anything larger than an old flip phone).

Suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm tired and confused and going to bed now to try to tackle this again in the morning.  Thanks in advance to anyone able to offer some insight.

Update 9/8:
Checking what user agent was being returned, found that the user agent spoofing I added to Chrome wasn't tricking Python in the least.  Interesting to note that it DID work with multiple live websites, so I'm not sure the deal there.  Information for a different time I supposed.

Added debugging tools to my phone to view page source, found that my phone was triggering the is_mobile to be True, but was still being returned the standard index.html page, not the index.mobile.html (as evidenced by not having the mobileStyles.css applied within the page, as index.mobile.html extends layout.mobile.html, which has a different css file)

From print statement for user agent:

```
<Storage {'is_mobile': True, 'is_tablet': False, 'os': <Storage {'name': 'Linux'}>, 'dist': <Storage {'version': '5.1.1', 'name': 'Android'}>, 'browser': <Storage {'version': '44.0.2403.117', 'name': 'Chrome'}>}>
```

Previously, when using the user agent spoofing on my laptop browser, it was returning:

```
<Storage {'os': <Storage {'name': 'Linux'}>, 'is_tablet': False, 'is_mobile': False, 'browser': <Storage {'version': '45.0.2454.85', 'name': 'Chrome'}>}>
```

I am now extra-befuddled.

Comment: Some further diagnostics would help. For example, is the above condition `True` with the mobile user agent (you can check via a print statement, or by writing to the view in that case)? If not, what is the exact user agent string (found in `request.env.http_user_agent`)?

Answer (score 1):

Of note, the above code is still failing, and I've verified that I am, in fact, entering the if statement on a True condition, and visiting the page from my phone is triggering a True condition.  I still would like to know why it's failing, however, I did find a workaround:

```
if request.user_agent().is_mobile:
    response.view = 'default/index.mobile.html'
```

The downside is I'll have slightly custom code in each function.  The upside is that it works.  If anyone has better ideas, I would LOVE to hear it.  Mostly because it annoys me that the example in the book doesn't appear to work, and I'd like to know what I did wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Mike, Have you asked this question on the web2py-users google group? They are very good about responding. Here's the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py